# React - pixel ratio - set 2x 3x images for retina devices

Tags: reactjs, retina-display

I am creating a react app.
I want the browser to server an image (twice bigger in resolution) to retina devices.

I am trying with 2x. I am trying in different ways:

The png is imported.
{retina} is the URL of the twice bigger image.
{logo} is the normal size image.

I have tried to implement it this way:

```
<picture>
<source srcset={`${retina} 2x, ${logo} 1x`} />
<img src={logo} alt="Flowers" />
</picture>
```

also this way:

```
<img srcset={`
${ratina} 2x,
${Logo} 1x,
`}
src={Logo}
></img>
```

and this way:

```
<picture>
<img src={logo} srcset={`${retina} 2x`} />
</picture>
```

and this way:

```
<img src={logo} srcset={`${retina} 2x`} />
```

For testing purposes I gave the retina png image a different color, just to notice it immediately when it works.

**Problem 1**:
In some of the above cases it shows twice the normal image, sometimes twice the retina images, but in none of the above cases it shows a normal image for 1x and 2x for retina devices. I am testing it on PC, iPhone, and with Chrome emulator with custom device set to pixel ratio 2.

**Problem 2** (that's not really a problem, but...):
In all cases the images are loaded in the browser as:

Can

1. anybody point out what I am doing wrong so that the 2x image is not
   showing up?
2. How can I import the image, so that the real image URL
   will be rendered and not a base64 without the need to create a
   `.env` file and set the `IMAGE_INLINE_SIZE_LIMIT` to 0? Any other way to achieve the same?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Almost there. You just need to name the attribute according to JSX style, which is `srcSet`. Also, whatever you put in `src` is considered the default resolution load, so in `srcSet` you just need the 2x and 3x, if applicable.

Full Code Example using an image called logo:

```
import logo from '../path-to/logo.png'
import logo2x from '../path-to/logo@2x.png'
import logo3x from '../path-to/logo@3x.png'

<img
  src={logo}
  srcSet={`${logo2x} 2x, ${logo3x} 3x`}
/>
```